# C# TextChanged event doesn't happend right away

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, event-handling

I'm building a WinFormApplication which allow the user to drag a document into a richTextBox which is loading the files content to the richTextBox. However the TextChange-event doesn't seem to happend emedietly after the text is changed, why could this be?

```
private void richTextBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
     ....
     ....
     richTextBox.Text = content;
     hasBeenEdited = false;

}
```

```
private void Form1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ....
     hasBeenEdited = true;
}
```

In the code above I have one DragDrop-event, the content of a file replaces the current richTextBox text. However the has been edited flag first get set to false, then true. I was hoping the flag would be set to true then false. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just call OtherOperation inside of TextChange after wordCounter?

Comment: `Form1_TextChanged() <-`  typo? `BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { OtherOperation(); }));`

Comment: I realize now this might been a bad example, but in the real application I'm setting diffrent flags so that won't work

Comment: Jimi, I'm bot surr what you mean, why does it look lika a tupp?

Comment: Would you mind showing us the full picture so that we can give a better answer?

Comment: I have updated the code and description

Comment: Because you have `Form1_TextChanged()` and not `richTextBox_TextChanged()` and you're setting `richTextBox.Text = content;` -- The new edit doesn't make sense. Post your actual code.